# How to add depdency in waf builder's wscript script

Tags: c++, waf

In my project (which uses waf/wscript based build system), I am now adding mongodb c++ driver APIs. I figured out that 'libmongoclient.a' is not getting added as a linker option (at compile time) and I get all undefined reference to the mongodb c++ driver API calls.

I want to understand, how do I modify my wscript so that it picks up the mongoclient related library by itself and links it properly. It perhaps involves updating the configuration function of wscript. I am new to the waf build system, and not sure how to change it.

```
I have built and installed the mongodb c++ driver as follows:
- INCLUDE: /usr/local/include/mongo/
- LIB:     /usr/local/lib/libmongoclient.a
```

I posted a similar question earlier in this regard, and the above one is more specific problem statement.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30020574/building-project-with-waf-script-and-eclipse

Since I am just invoking ./waf from within eclipse, I believe, the options that I specify into Eclipse's build environment are not being picked up by the waf (and hence the library option for mongoclient).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out and the steps are as follows:

1. Added following check in the configure command/function.

   conf.check_cfg(package='libmongoclient', args=['--cflags', '--libs'],
                  uselib_store='MONGOCLIENT', mandatory=True)
2. After this step, we need to add a package configuration file (.pc) into /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig path. This is the file where we specify the paths to lib and headers. Pasting the content of this file below.

   prefix=/usr/local
   libdir=/usr/local/lib
   includedir=/usr/local/include/mongo

   Name: libmongoclient
   Description: Mongodb C++ driver
   Version: 0.2
   Libs: -L${libdir} -lmongoclient
   Cflags: -I${includedir}
3. Added the above library into the build function to the sepcific program which depends on the above dependency (i.e. MongoClient).

   mobility = bld(
       target='bin/mobility',
       features='cxx cxxprogram',
       source='src/main.cpp',
       use='mob-objects MONGOCLIENT',
       )